# How to stretch div based on body's padding?

Tags: html, css, menu, nav

I have a problem with styling with CSS.

I can't fit the #main to the screen. I have a menu on the left side and i would like to have the main screen from the right next to the menu.

```
body {
    background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 30px 100px 0 100px;
}

nav {
  line-height:30px;
  width:20%;
  float:left;
  padding:5px;        
}

#main{
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  float:left;
  padding:10px;
}
```

Here you are the screenshot how it is looking now:

[image]

How should I place "Content of the document" (#main) to be next to the nav?

EDIT: I have placed my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/47tjbnrt/

Comment: Just give `display:inline-block;` to your `nav`. And let me know.

Comment: Also need your HTML to solve issue. Better if you could create a similar demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/). It would be easy to help you out.

Comment: It's all about how the box model works. The total width of an element is width+padding by default. With basic math you see that it's getting over 100% with that. To change the box model to include the padding in the width you can apply box-sizing: border-box either on both nav and main or apply it on the global selector : * { box-sizing: border-box; }

Comment: @divy3993 see the link. It is below of the description.

Comment: @divy3993 display:inline-block didn't work :(

Comment: See this, http://jsfiddle.net/qox9v4jt/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by your adding padding to the width. `width` is the width of its content and you set one to 80%, the other to 20%, and then add padding on top of that. Padding is the area around the content and, therefore, the width. That is why your second div drops down.

Either remove the padding or reduce the width of your elements.

Answer (score -1):

```
body {
    background-color: lightgray;
    padding: 30px 100px 0 100px;
}
header {
    text-align: center;
}
nav {
    line-height:30px;
    width:20%;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;
}

#main {
    width: 70%;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
}
```

I changed the width to 70%, since you have a lot of padding. (Also removed the `position: relative` from your `#main`, do you have anything with `position: absolute` inside the main section?)

Also changed the width to 70%, since you have a lot of padding.